# javascript inside java/jsp code

Tags: javascript, jsp

i've written the javascript code inside

**myjsp.jsp**

```
<%
try {
    String id=request.getParameter("id");
%>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        alert("TRY"+ <%=id %>);
        document.getElementById("mytext").readonly="readonly";
    </script>
<%
} catch (Exception e) {
%>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        alert("CATCH"+<%=e%>);
    </script>
<%
}
%>
```

So, whenever value will be passed into the `id` it'll show the value of `id` into the alertbox and also it'll make the textbox whose id is **mytext** will become disable.

So, when i'm executing the **myjsp.jsp** page without passing the parameter it shows the output as **TRYnull**, but when i'm passing the value into `id` then it's not showing anything, not even alertbox. Any idea !!

My jsp page

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
       <%
try {
    String id=request.getParameter("id");
%>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        alert("TRY"+ "<%=id %>");
        alert(document.getElementById("mytext"));
    </script>
<%
} catch (Exception e) {
%>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        alert("CATCH"+<%=e%>);
    </script>
<%
}
%>

            <input id="mytext" name="mytext" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: JSP and JavaScript does not run in sync. JSP produces HTML/JavaScript. Open page in browser, rightclick it and *View Source* to see yourself.

Comment: FYI if the exception is for example unparsable date and has doub quotes it will give error in browser console !

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because when you pass no request parameter of `id` it will, as you've mentioned, be `null`. In this case the following JavaScript will be produced:

```
alert("TRY" + null);
```

This is valid JavaScript so this is why you see `TRYnull`.

However, if you pass in an `id` request parameter the following JavaScript will be generated:

```
alert("TRY" + foo);
```

Although this is syntactically valid JavaScript it is almost certain to produce an error (and therefore not show the `alert`) because here `foo` is a variable which is highly likely to be `undefined`.

If you have a look in the JavaScript console you will probably see something like:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

What you need to do it put quotes around your scriptlet so that the value of `id` is treated as a `String` and not a variable, i.e.

```
alert("TRY <%= id %>");
```